# How the [apply] tag is being used

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently flagged a R questions using the [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apply) tag. If you check the [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apply) tag the description says:

> A Lisp function to call a function with a list of arguments.

While the questions are mostly about the R apply family functions. While I don't know a thing about Lisp, I'm sure that was not the intended use of the tag. On the other hand, apply functions make a good portion of R questions.

In fact, checking [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apply) history it seems it referred to R until [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8489109/5), while [revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8489109/6) (Dec '15) was changed to Lisp.

So, how to proceed? New tag for R? Rewording the [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apply) description? Revert revision 6? Any other ideas?

Comment: I find the tag useless... JS has apply stuff, Python has apply stuff, what the heck is lapply, sapplay and mapply?

Comment: @Braiam what can we do? Edit the tag to fit every language? Propose deletion? At the very least revision 6 must be undone imo.

Comment: Being used or being applied?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Revision 7 now makes [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apply) for every language that contains it.
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8489109/revisions

### EDIT

I took the liberty of writing a small section for [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) seeing there are sections for [lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: Now I see someone disagreed, it would be productive if said person could give us some input on the matter.